# How to remove particular file of a changeset?

Tags: tfs, changeset

As stated in the title, is it possible to remove a particular file within a changeset that been checked in into TFS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the steps below:

1. Roll back the changset:

[image]

2. Then you'll see the rollback changes for all files in Pending Changes:

[image]

3. Undo the changes for the files you want to keep, and check in the pending changes:

[image]

Comment: In this case, it is create new Changeset? Keep old ChangeSet or modify this changeset?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cannot change a changeset, but you can make a new one which only rollback parts of the previous changeset as @Cece has specified in his answer.